# How to display WebDynpro ABAP in ABAP report?

Tags: report, abap, sap-gui, webdynpro, function-module

I've just started coding ABAP for a few days and I have a task to call the report from transaction `SE38` and have

> the report's result shown on the screen of the WebDynPro application `SE80`.

The report take the user input ( e.g: Material Number, Material Type, Plant, Sale Org. ) as a condition for querying, so the WebDynPro application must allow user to key in this parameters.

In some related article they were talking about using `SUBMIT rep EXPORTING LIST TO MEMORY`  and `CALL FUNCTION 'LIST_FROM_MEMORY'` but so far I really have no idea to implement it.

Any answers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take a large clue bat and "convince" whoever gave you that assignment that a) this is not a specification but a rather weird idea and b) you need the proper training BEFORE you start messing with a mission-critical ERP/CRM/whatever system. IMHO this question cannot be answered with anything else than "get the appropriate training" - it usually takes weeks to teach and learn the necessary basic knowledge.

Comment: Totally agreed. But unfortunately, I've got to find proper training from the internet and that 'whoever' gave this task as a practice for me and I must get it done nonetheless. lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can export it to PDF. Therefore, when a user clicks on a link, you run the conversion and display the file in the browser window.

To do so, you start by creating a JOB using the following code below:

```
  constants c_name type tbtcjob-jobname value 'YOUR_JOB_NAME'.

  data v_number type tbtcjob-jobcount.
  data v_print_parameters type pri_params.

  call function 'JOB_OPEN'
    exporting
      jobname          = c_name
    importing
      jobcount         = v_number
    exceptions
      cant_create_job  = 1
      invalid_job_data = 2
      jobname_missing  = 3
      others           = 4.

  if sy-subrc = 0.
    commit work and wait.
  else.
    EXIT. "// todo: err handling here
  endif.
```

Then, you need to get the printer parameters in order to submit the report:

```
call function 'GET_PRINT_PARAMETERS'
  exporting
    destination            = 'LP01'
    immediately            = space
    new_list_id            = 'X'
    no_dialog              = 'X'
    user                   = sy-uname
  importing
    out_parameters         = v_print_parameters
  exceptions
    archive_info_not_found = 1
    invalid_print_params   = 2
    invalid_archive_params = 3
    others                 = 4.

v_print_parameters-linct = 55.
v_print_parameters-linsz = 1.
v_print_parameters-paart = 'LETTER'.
```

Now you submit your report using the filters that apply. Do not forget to add the job parameters to it, as the code below shows:

```
  submit your_report_name
         to sap-spool
         spool parameters v_print_parameters
         without spool dynpro
         with ...(insert all your filters here)
         via job c_name number v_number
         and return.

  if sy-subrc = 0.
    commit work and wait.
  else.
    EXIT. "// todo: err handling here
  endif.
```

After that, you close the job:

```
  call function 'JOB_CLOSE'
    exporting
      jobcount             = v_number
      jobname              = c_name
      strtimmed            = 'X'
    exceptions
      cant_start_immediate = 1
      invalid_startdate    = 2
      jobname_missing      = 3
      job_close_failed     = 4
      job_nosteps          = 5
      job_notex            = 6
      lock_failed          = 7
      others               = 8.

  if sy-subrc = 0.
    commit work and wait.
  else.
    EXIT. "// todo: err handling here
  endif.
```

Now the job will proceed and you'll need to wait for it to complete. Do it with a loop. Once the job is completed, you can get it's spool output and convert to PDF.

```
  data v_rqident type tsp01-rqident.

  data v_job_head type tbtcjob.

  data t_job_steplist type tbtcstep occurs 0 with header line.

  data t_pdf like tline occurs 0 with header line.

  do 200 times.

    wait up to 1 seconds.

    call function 'BP_JOB_READ'
      exporting
        job_read_jobcount     = v_number
        job_read_jobname      = c_name
        job_read_opcode       = '20'
      importing
        job_read_jobhead      = v_job_head
      tables
        job_read_steplist     = t_job_steplist
      exceptions
        invalid_opcode        = 1
        job_doesnt_exist      = 2
        job_doesnt_have_steps = 3
        others                = 4.

    read table t_job_steplist index 1.

    if not t_job_steplist-listident is initial.
      v_rqident = t_job_steplist-listident.
      exit.
    else.
      clear v_job_head.
      clear t_job_steplist.
      clear t_job_steplist[].
    endif.

  enddo.

  check not v_rqident is initial.

  call function 'CONVERT_ABAPSPOOLJOB_2_PDF'
    exporting
      src_spoolid              = v_rqident
      dst_device               = 'LP01'
    tables
      pdf                      = t_pdf
    exceptions
      err_no_abap_spooljob     = 1
      err_no_spooljob          = 2
      err_no_permission        = 3
      err_conv_not_possible    = 4
      err_bad_destdevice       = 5
      user_cancelled           = 6
      err_spoolerror           = 7
      err_temseerror           = 8
      err_btcjob_open_failed   = 9
      err_btcjob_submit_failed = 10
      err_btcjob_close_failed  = 11
      others                   = 12.
```

If you're going to send it via HTTP, you may need to convert it to BASE64 as well.

```
  field-symbols <xchar> type x.
  data v_offset(10) type n.
  data v_char type c.
  data v_xchar(2) type x.
  data v_xstringdata_aux type xstring.
  data v_xstringdata type xstring.
  data v_base64data type string.
  data v_base64data_aux type string.

  loop at t_pdf.
    do 134 times.
      v_offset = sy-index - 1.
      v_char = t_pdf+v_offset(1).
      assign v_char to <xchar> casting type x.
      concatenate v_xstringdata_aux <xchar> into v_xstringdata_aux in byte mode.
    enddo.
    concatenate v_xstringdata v_xstringdata_aux into v_xstringdata in byte mode.
    clear v_xstringdata_aux.
  endloop.

  call function 'SCMS_BASE64_ENCODE_STR'
    exporting
      input  = v_xstringdata
    importing
      output = v_base64data.

  v_base64data_aux = v_base64data.

  while strlen( v_base64data_aux ) gt 255.
    clear t_base64data.
    t_base64data-data = v_base64data_aux.
    v_base64data_aux = v_base64data_aux+255.
    append t_base64data.
  endwhile.

  if not v_base64data_aux is initial.
    t_base64data-data = v_base64data_aux.
    append t_base64data.
  endif.
```

And you're done!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As previous speakers said, you should do extensive training before implementing such stuff in productive environment.
However, calling WebdynPro ABAP within report can be done with the help of `WDY_EXECUTE_IN_PLACE` function module. You should pass there Webdyn Pro application and necessary parameters.

```
CALL FUNCTION 'WDY_EXECUTE_IN_PLACE'
 EXPORTING
*   PROTOCOL                     =
    INTERNALMODE                 = ' '
*   SMARTCLIENT                  =
    APPLICATION                  = 'Z_MY_WEBDYNPRO'
*   CONTAINER_NAME               =
    PARAMETERS                   = lt_parameters
    SUPPRESS_OUTPUT              =
    TRY_TO_USE_SAPGUI_THEME      = ' '
 IMPORTING
    OUT_URL                       = ex_url
.

IF sy-subrc <> 0.
* Implement suitable error handling here
ENDIF.
```